# Texture not rendering properly with shader

Tags: three.js, glsl, textures

I have a video texture which I have to input into a glsl shader. I am using threejs for this. My code is as follows

```
let texture = new THREE.VideoTexture(video);
texture.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
texture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
let vertexShader = `
        varying vec2 vuv;
        void main() {
        vuv = uv; 
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
        }`
let fragmentShader = `
      varying vec2 vuv;
      uniform sampler2D texture0;
      void main() {
          gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture0,vuv);
    }`;
let uniform = { texture0: { type:'t',texture: texture } };
let material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({ uniforms: uniform, fragmentShader: fragmentShader, vertexShader: vertexShader })
let geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1000, 1000);
let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
this.scene.add(mesh);
```

But this is giving only a black color instead of texture. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let uniform = { texture0: { type:'t',texture: texture } };`

Has to be like that:

`let uniform = { texture0: { value: texture } };`